# Azure AD - Getting Claims with offline_access scope (ADAL Library)

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, openid-connect, adal, claims-based-identity

I am using Microsoft libraries to implement OAuth against Azure AD in a .NET web application.

I am using the AcquireTokenSilentAsync method based on persisted cached tokens to get an AuthenticationResult object. This object contains a UserInfo property which can be used to get Claim Values to create a ClaimsIdentity object.

I am trying to understand which scopes to pass to the OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions' Scope parameter.

I was using OpenIDConnectScope.OpenIDProfile value which translates to 'openid profile' - this was successfully retrieving the claims. But it does not return a refresh token to handle refreshing the access token beyond its expiry (which is what I want).

So I figured out I needed to use OpenIDConnectScope.OfflineAccess which translates to 'offline_access'. This used on its own returns an AuthenticationResult.UserInfo object with all its properties set to 'null'.

I figured I would try to use multiple scopes; something like 'openid profile offline_access' but as long as there is 'offline_access' within the Scope parameter values, the UserInfo object is always returning null values!

Why would this be happening? What is the correct way to be enable refreshing the access token while also being able to retrieve the UserInfo object for creating a ClaimsIdentity object?

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you are using ADAL.NET v3 right?

ADAL v2 used to expose the refresh token because you had to handle refresh yourself. With ADAL v3, this is done automatically by the library.

Your code should be something like:

```
try
{
 result = await authContext.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(graphResourceId, clientId);
}
catch (AdalException adalException) 
{
 if (adalException.ErrorCode == AdalError.FailedToAcquireTokenSilently || adalException.ErrorCode == AdalError.UserInteractionRequired)
 {
  result = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(graphResourceId,
                                               clientCred, 
                                               userAssertion);
 }
}
```

See details [here](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/wiki/Service-to-service-calls-on-behalf-of-the-user).

Comment: Yes I am using the latest stable version of ADAL, and my code looks exactly like yours. Additionally I am using an SQL database to persist the Token cache; the authContext is created using this token cache. The idea is to be able to authenticate using the cached token from a completely different browser session without having to enter the credentials every time. In this scenario entering the username and pass would only be required first time round. The issue is that acquiring the token silently only works if the access token has not expired (within an hour timeframe). Any idea?

Comment: where do you see which adal version you use ?